# How to disable Ctrl+Shift+u keyboard shortcut (unicode-selector) in Fedora 39 KDE-Spin (Wayland)

Tags: fedora, shortcuts, kde, unicode, wayland

**0. How can I disable the Ctrl+Shift+u keyboard shortcut (unicode-selector) in Fedora 39 KDE-Spin (Wayland-Session)?**

Whenever I hit this key combination on a **GTK+-app**, the infamous underlined "u" appears, expexting me to write a number to finally print a unicode-character.

I do not want that as I use Ctrl+Shift+u to underline text especially in LibreOffice.

**1. The System:**

- Fedora 39 KDE-Spin (Gnome is not and hasn't been installed on the system prior). All updates are up to date.
- Wayland Session
- Input method: the "Input Method Selector"-App says "No input method".
- ibus is installed but the ibus-daemon is not running (-> but see "4." down below)

**2. Affected GTK+-apps**

**2.1.** Affected apps with the Unicode-selector appearing:

Native-.rpm-Apps:

- Wayland: Gnome Document-Scanner, Celluliod, dconf-Editor

Flatpaks:

- Wayland: Firefox, Thunderbird, Libreoffice, Vivaldi, Xournal++, Joplin, Flatseal

**2.2.** Slighty differently affected apps #1 - when hitting the key-combination the keyboard stops accepting input unless I hit "esc". Remarkably the problem does not occur as long as the ibus-daemon is running (for I have deleted the combination in the "ibus-setup".):

Flatpaks:

- XWayland: GIMP

**2.3.** Slightly differently affected apps #2 - when hitting the key-combination the keyboard stops accepting input unless I hit "esc". *In contrast to (2.2) the problem persists wether the ibus-daemon is running or not:*

Flatpaks:

- Wayland: Inkscape

**3. NOT affected** by the Problem are the following Apps. These Apps do not show the unicode-selector nor stop accepting keyboard-input when hitting the combination:

Native-.rpm-Apps:

- XWayland: VLC (unsure if GTK+ ?)

Flatpaks:

- Wayland: Pinta, Nextcloud-Desktop-Client (unsure is GTK+ ?)

(and all other non-GTK+-Apps, eg. Dolphin, KWrite, Okular,...)

**4. Unsatisfying workaround:**

**4.1** Set the following environment variables in "~/.bashrc":

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

**4.2.** Re-login with your user.

**4.3.** Start the ibus-daemon.

**4.4.** => Results: unless in Inkscape (Flatpak, XWayland -> see above "2.3") neither the unicode-selector appears anymore nor do the programs stop accepting keyboard inputs.

**4.5.** There has to be a solution without running ibus just to delete the combination in ibus. As the problem occurs without ibus it should not be related to ibus in the first place, right?

**5. Other unsuccessful attempts:**

**5.1.** The combination is not assigned to any function in the KDE System Settings, so I wasn't able to delete it from a potentially existing function in the KDE System Settings.
However I tried to assign it to a KDE System function and it worked: I assigned it to the "expand windows vertically"-function just to see the result and all programs obeyed the KDE System Settings assignment and expanded vertically.
As soon as I deleted the combination from the "expand windows vertically"-function again, the problem occured again.

**5.2.** I also could not find any assignment with the dconf-editor.

Thank You very much in advance and have happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

KDE usually ships with the fcitx5 input method. To configure, try System Settings -> Regional Settings -> Input Method -> configure addons (near the bottom)

Look for Unicode. You can rebind this by clicking the configure button, or check Show Advance options at the bottom and disable it.

[image: here is an image]